# Selecting a tuple index using a variable in Swift

Tags: string, swift, tuples

That is what i am trying to do:

```
var i = 0
var string = "abcdef"

for value in string
{
    value.[Put value of variable i here] = "a"

    i++
}
```

How can i insert the value of i in the code?

Comment: The var "value" in that loop for is a character, not a tuple. Strings in swift are a collection of characters. link from apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

Comment: I know but i can access the value using value.0 or value.1

Comment: A) That's probably an implementation detail not to be relied upon, and B) assign for what purpose?

Comment: I have a string with username and password separated with a space and i need to get every letter before the space and append it to username

So i need to do something like username.i = value

Comment: And i can't use username[i] like in other languages

Comment: Why do you have username and password in one string? Something is wrong here.

Comment: I have no choice to do it in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is probably just convert it to an NSMutableString:

```
let string = "abcdef".mutableCopy() as NSMutableString

println( "\(string)")

for var i = 0; i < string.length; ++i {
  string.replaceCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(i, 1), withString: "a")
}

println( "\(string)")
```

Yes, it's a bit ugly but it works.

Answer (score 1):

A much cleaner way is to use Swifts `map` function:

```
var string = "abcdef"
let result = map(string) { (c) -> Character in
    "a"
}
println("\(result)") // aaaaaa
```

You should just be able to use the following but this doesn't compile:

```
map(string) { "a" }
```

In you comments you mention you want to split up the string on a space, you can just use this for that:

```
let stringWithSpace = "abcdef 012345"
let splitString = stringWithSpace.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
println("\(splitString[0])") // abcdef
println("\(splitString[1])") // 012345
```